# I want to add charge and balances records and update it into other column or the same balance column, but just the first record is beeing affected

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM charges";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($results);

for ($i=0; $i <=$count ; $i++) { 
    $id = $row['c_id'];
    $newBalance = $row['charge']+$row['balance'];
    $query = "UPDATE charges SET balance = $newBalance WHERE c_id = $id";
    mysqli_query($link, $query)
}
```

?>

that's my php code
and the below pic is my database tables

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NngsK.png)

Comment: You make an $i, but I cannot see that you do anything with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is:

```
UPDATE charges SET balance = balance + charge
```

With php it is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE charges SET balance = balance + charge";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```